# how to get an array from a data frame

Tags: r, arrays, dataframe

How can I get an array form a column in data frame satisfying a condition?

example:

```
x=data.frame(pn=c('a','b','c','d','e','f'),price=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

Then, for a given list of pn (an array that can have any size), like this:

```
y=c('a','b','f','a','a','b','b','a','f','f')
```

I want an array of prices regarding y. The expected output is:

```
1,2,6,1,1,2,2,1,6,6
```

(No loop or lambda function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a named vector to match

```
unname(setNames(x$price, x$pn)[y])
#[1] 1 2 6 1 1 2 2 1 6 6
```